# Get first few kilobytes of remote file through fabric

Tags: python, fabric, scp

How do I get the first few thousand bytes of a remote file in Python?

Using something like fabric I could call `get`

```
from fabric.api import get
get('remote-path.csv', 'local-head.csv')
```

Unfortunately this would copy the entire file.  I only want to inspect the first few hundred lines.  Is there a cheap, Python accessible, cross-platform way to do this?

Comment: Not cross-platform solution, `run('head -n XX remote-path.csv > tmp.csv')`, then `get('tmp.csv', 'local-head.csv')` and `run('rm tmp.csv')`. It doesn't work if your remote server is Windows, or you cannot write on remote server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do this easily with fabric.  With `paramiko` you can do something like:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
//auth stuff
//ssh.connect()
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
with sftp.file('/home/ubuntu/iris.csv','r') as f:
    for i in range(5):
        print(f.readline())
```